# How do I filter out empty hashes from an array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, grep

I have an array of hashes like so:

```
my @array = [
             {1 => "Test1"},
             {},
             {1 => "Test2"},
            ];
```

I try to filter out the {} from this array so that the end result is an array without any {} like so:

```
my @array = [
             {1 => "Test1"},
             {1 => "Test2"},
            ];
```

I tried using something like this but it doesn't work:

```
my @new_array = grep(!/{}/, @array);
```

Comment: If you really did mean to have an array with just one element, then the solution would be `my @new_array = map [ grep %$_, @$_ ], @array;`. I doubt it, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `grep` command can take a regex as argument, but also an arbitrary block of code. And please do not try to match Perl code with regexes, this doesn't work.

Instead, we ask for the number of keys in the anonymous hash:

```
my @new_array = grep { keys %$_ } @array;
```

This selects all hashes in `@array` where the number of keys is not zero.

Comment: +1. You can omit `scalar` here, though it adds clarity to this code.

Comment: I actually think it is clearer without scalar ... a grep block is always interpreted as boolean anyway.

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, Hum, that makes me wonder... `%$_` is special in boolean context (more efficient than it would be in other scalar context). I wonder if counts a grep callback result as boolean. If so, you could drop `keys`. Technically, you can drop `keys` either way, it's just a question of efficiency.

Comment: @ikegami I thought keys was required, but I guess not. It seems it is faster though.
`Benchmark: timing 10000000 iterations of with_keys, without_keys...

 with_keys:  8 wallclock secs ( 8.59 usr +  0.01 sys =  8.60 CPU) @ 1162790.70/s (n=10000000)

without_keys: 25 wallclock secs (25.05 usr +  0.03 sys = 25.08 CPU) @ 398724.08/s (n=10000000)`

Comment: @Dondi, that is interesting.  I suppose it is because of the function of a hash in scalar context: "the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash." http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, It's slower in general because building the string `4/16` takes time. But newer versions optimised what `%h` returns in **boolean** context, so it would be equally fast. (Well, one less op, so a few ns faster). PS - I never trust benchmarks I haven't seen. Too easy to make errors. I'd run my own, but I need to head to bed.

Comment: @ikegami I see. I used on 5.12. What version should they be equal in speed?

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, `with_keys => 'my $x; $x = 1 if keys %h;'`: 4035769/s /// `with_hash => 'my $x; $x = 1 if %h;'`: 4672531/s.  I used 5.14.2 and a non empty hash (13 elements).

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, The optimisation was added to 5.12.0 according to [perl5120delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html).

Comment: A great discussion in comments. So I have to +1 the faster variant!

Answer (score 6):

1) A small correction:

```
my @array = [
    {1 => "Test1"},
    {},
    {1 => "Test2"},
];
```

Is really a 1-element array with array ref inside. You probably need

```
my @array = (
    {1 => "Test1"},
    {},
    {1 => "Test2"},
);
```

2) The grep expr:

```
my @new_array = grep { scalar %$_ } @array;
```

Hash returns 0 in scalar context if it's empty, and something like "17/32" otherwise. So the `grep` will only pick non-empty arrays.

**UPDATE:** As @raina77ow suggests, scalar may be omitted! So it's even shorter (though I still prefer explicit `scalar` for clarity in *my* code).

```
my @new_array = grep { %$_ } @array;
```

Comment: Or even `my @new_array = grep %$_, @array;` :)

Comment: I wonder what's people problems with the expression form of `grep` when they do `foo() if bar();` and `foo() for bar();` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
my @new_array = grep(keys %$_, @array);
```

The `/.../` in your code is a regular expression.  It checks if each element in the array contains certain characters.  However, your array contains references to hashes, so you need to dereference each element and  then see if that is empty.

Also, this declaration is incorrect:

```
my @array = [
             {1 => "Test1"},
             {},
             {1 => "Test2"},
            ];
```

The brackets create an array reference, while you just want an array.  Just use parentheses instead:

```
my @array = (
             {1 => "Test1"},
             {},
             {1 => "Test2"},
            );
```